# Flowchart software for Raspbian

Tags: raspbian

Is there any low RAM and CPU usage flow chart software for creating flow charts on Raspbian? It would have to be a GUI software that is in the repositories.

Comment: What about some of the web options gliffy or lucidchart among many others this would remove the resource limitations?

Comment: It would have to be software as there will be no internet connection all of the time.

Comment: Why dont you use a online web based platform independent flowchart software like [this one](http://creately.com)?

Answer (score 5):

If you must have a GUI, there's the venerable [Xfig](http://xfig.org/). It's *old*; I was using it at university about 25 years ago. It's reliable and has a large flowchart symbol library:

[image: xfig flowchart symbols]

But if you want really lightweight, [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) is the way to go. It has a simple graphing language, and has a previewer, so you don't need a GUI. Here's an example:

```
digraph {
    label="graphviz flowchart GUI decisions"

    start[shape="box", style=rounded];
    end[shape="box", style=rounded];
    if_gui[shape="diamond", 
      label="Do you\nthink you\nneed a\nflowchart\nGUI?"];
    no_you_dont[shape="parallelogram", 
      label="No, you\ndon't."];

    start -> if_gui;
    if_gui -> end[label="no"];
    if_gui -> no_you_dont[label="yes"];
    no_you_dont -> end;
}
```

You can preview the result directly:

```
dot -Tx11 flowchart.dot
```

[image: graphviz preview]

(Both of these examples were run on a Raspberry Pi running stock Raspbian.)

Answer (score 4):

I can't speak to how lightweight it is but dia is available from the repository. It can be installed with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install dia
```

Here is a tutorial for [creating flowcharts](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/11/5-easy-steps-to-create-a-flowchat-using-dia/) with dia.

Comment: Steve Robillard: Dia looks great in its descriptions! Unfortunately (for me), having installed it on my RPi 2, when run it displays the startup logo, flashes a window then terminates with a Segmentation fault as follows: ** (dia-normal:9312): CRITICAL **: dia_renderer_set_size: assertion 'irenderer != NULL' failed /
Segmentation fault Is something else required? What's different about your RPi?

Comment: @rlsj If I remeber correctly this is how I fixed the problem http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/26099/56

Answer (score 0):

The only option I'm aware of is calligraflow.

I can't judge whether you would think it low ram and CPU.

sudo apt-get install calligraflow

I use jessie/sid.  I don't know if the package is available in wheezy.